# How to write data into multiple sheets of single workbook based on different conditions?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to categorize test cases into 4 categories:

1. Manual-Smoke
2. Manual-Regression
3. Automated-Smoke
4. Automated-Regression

I have a python code which will give me dictionary in this way:

```
  "ABC": {
    "id1": "name1",
    "id2": "name2",
    "id3": "name3"
  }
```

I have written following code using `xlsxwriter` but this iterates through all the sheets but it saves only last. In my excel WB, I only get one last sheet.

```
def createExcelSheetTC(self,testcase):
    workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
    self.format_excelWB(workbook)
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx') as workbook:
        self.format_excelWB(workbook) ##Initialize formatting of WB
        if testcase == self.manualSmoke:
            ws_manualSmoke=workbook.add_worksheet('Manual-Smoke Cases')
            self.writeTCExcel(testcase,ws_manualSmoke)
        elif testcase == self.manualRegression:
            ws_manualRegression=workbook.add_worksheet('Manual-Regression Cases')
            self.writeTCExcel(testcase,ws_manualRegression)
        elif testcase == self.automatedSmoke:
            ws_autoSmoke=workbook.add_worksheet('Automated-Smoke Cases')
            self.writeTCExcel(testcase,ws_autoSmoke)
        elif testcase == self.automatedRegression:
            ws_autoRegression=workbook.add_worksheet('Automated-Regression Cases')
            self.writeTCExcel(testcase,ws_autoRegression)
    workbook.close()

def writeTCExcel(self,tc,worksheet):
    ##Logic to write testcase in EXCEL
    ## This is correct as per requirements


self.manualSmoke=self.get_test_cases(args*)
self.createExcelSheetTC(testcase=self.manualSmoke)

self.manualRegression=self.get_test_cases(args*)
self.createExcelSheetTC(testcase=self.manualRegression)   

self.automatedSmoke=self.get_test_cases(args*)
self.createExcelSheetTC(testcase=self.automatedSmoke)

self.automatedRegression=self.get_test_cases(args*)
self.createExcelSheetTC(testcase=self.automatedRegression)
```

Using the above code I get **'Automated-Regression'** cases but not the other 3. It looks like it only saves at last & overwrite all other write ups.

Comment: Is this happening because `args*` is the same for all four calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got resolved by using the following method.

```
import xlsxwriter
d1 = {
      "ABC": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3"
  },
   "XYZ": {
    "key4": "val4",
    "key5": "val5",
    "key6": "val6"
  }
}
d2= {  "MNO": {
    "key7": "val7",
    "key8": "val8",
    "key9": "val9"
  }
}


def create_xls_writer(tc):
    workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('xlsxwriter.xlsx')
    print tc
    ws1=workbook.add_worksheet('abc')
    ws2=workbook.add_worksheet('xyz')

    worksheet = [ws1,ws2]

    for each_tc in tc:
        if each_tc==d1:
            writeTCEXcel(each_tc,ws1)
        elif each_tc==d2:
            writeTCEXcel(each_tc,ws2)

    workbook.close()

def writeTCEXcel(something,worksheet):
##Logic to write **Something**  in EXCEL



create_xls_writer([d1,d2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwritening your `xlsx` on every call to `def createExcelSheetTC`,so you see only the last.

move these outside `def createExcelSheetTC`and call it **only** once.

```
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
self.format_excelWB(workbook)
...
workbook.close()
```